# Eclipse c++ twists code flow

Tags: c++, eclipse

with the following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num;
    cout << "Insert number: " << endl; // prints "Insert number:"
    cin >> num; //Reads num
    cout << num; //prints num

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

i get the following result in the internal console of eclipse:

```
Insert number:         //code in line 6
3                      //code in line 7 (Input)
Press any button...    //code in line 10
                       //empty line after pressing any button
3                      //code in line 8?!?!?
```

And I have no idea why this is happening. It looks like eclipse just twists the execution of the code. But why and how could i solve this problem?

Comment: Flush the output: `cout << num << endl;`

Comment: You solve this by not using `system("PAUSE");` and instead tell eclipse to not close the window immediately. A quick hack that will produce more problems later is `std::cout << num << std::flush;`.

Comment: @nwp " A quick hack that will produce more problems later " - what problems?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Problems like unmaintainable code due to having to remember to flush the buffer every time before using `system` and incompatibility with systems that don't have a program called `PAUSE` and issues with IDEs that are configured correctly which now pause twice before exiting. And those are just the ones I can think of right now.

Comment: Better put a break point at return 0 rather than using system("PAUSE");

Comment: @nwp Needing to flush output is a common thing to have to do, whether you use crap like system("pause") or not.

Comment: @Hariom Better to learn how to use your IDE properly.

Comment: @NeilButterworth You only manually flush if you work with bad libraries. The STL is required to automatically flush if you use, for example, `std::cin` or `printf` (unless you explicitly turn that off) and in the destructor of `std::cout`. Manually flushing buffers is something you only do in very rare cases. This is not one of them.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `system("PAUSE")` anyway. Its not good practice, and antivirus programs _hate_ it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called *buffering*. Output to `std::cout` is *buffered*, and won't be displayed unless the buffer is flushed (which happens at program exit) or you explicitly flush it with the [`flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) or [`endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) standard [I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

That the output of the `PAUSE` command is displayed is because it bypasses the `std::cout` buffering of your process, and either writes directly to the console window or because it flushes its own internal buffers (the `PAUSE` command will be run as an unrelated process, with its own possible buffering).